# send multiple ajax request to webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have this lines of code that send multiple ajax request to wcf

```
$(".cWarpO").each(function () {

                  if ($(this).find(".newId").length > 0) {
                        counter++;

                        var Mapping = new Array();
                        Mapping[0] = counter;
                        Mapping[1] = $(this).find(".idN").html(); //new id
                        Mapping[2] = $(this).find(".idO").html();
                        Mapping[3] = newCourseId;
                        Mapping[4] = courseOldId;
                        Mapping[5] = isGenric;
                        Mapping[6] = oldGenricCourse;

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/WebServices/general.svc/mappingCourses",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ Mapping: Mapping }),
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {



                            }
                        });


                    }

                });
```

the webservice operation is update the db.
Since the jquery ajax is work unsynchronized it's sending the server multipal request that end in error:"An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

I thins it's because the database is trying to open new connection every time.

Any idea how to loop on the array in a synchronized way?

Thanks

Baaroz

Comment: you should rethink about your logic to just send all datas using only one ajax request

Comment: maybe adding "async:false" to jquery ajax?

Comment: this would be a fix but the worst one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it synchronously which may lock the clients browser (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/14220323#14220323)), why don't use send the requests recursively - ie whenever a request finishes send the next request:

```
var mapCourse = function($ele, index) {
    if(index < $ele.length) {
            //stuff
            $.ajax({
                url: "/WebServices/general.svc/mappingCourses",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ Mapping: Mapping }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//you don't need to set this
                success: function (data) {
                    //stuff

                    mapCourse($ele, index + 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

mapCourse($(".cWarpO"), 0);
```